# phantomjs image width not getting as expected

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot, viewport, browser-width

when i take screenshots using phanomjs using the following code works fine and I am getting width as 1920px and height is not a problem for me.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("http://www.google.com", function start(status) {
page.render('google_home.png');
 phantom.exit();
```

but, when i set the dimension as

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 780 };
```

the resulting image width is 602px.

**how to set width for taking screenshot using page.render() function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can't. because "http://www.google.com" forcefully set the minimum width of the document above some 600px. so, when i call `page.render()` it renders the complete document which is having a width not 320px.

Answer (score 0):

If the minimum page width (or fixed width) is bigger than the viewport size, then PhantomJS will render a screenshot that has the same width as the page (body).

You can of course crop the screenshot by setting the corresponding dimension and position using [`page.clipRect`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html).

You can also experiment with the [`zoomFactor`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/zoom-factor.html).